# Adding to array with specified index in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to *javascript*, I have created 2 functions, **createInput()** which creates input boxes with a *name* parameter when called and appends them to a  tag, **newTwo()** which calls createInput() twice with two different names.

I cannot seem to provide a index for the two name elements and make it increment each time the newTwo() is called. I need this so that I can trace the field values as a pair.

```
function createInput(name) 
{

    var input = document.createElement("input");

    input.setAttribute("type", "text");
    input.setAttribute("name", name);

    var form = document.getElementById("foobar");

    form.appendChild(input);

}

function newTwo()
{
    var $i = 0;
    createInput("first_name[" + $i + "]");
    createInput("last_name[" + $i + "]");
    $i++;
}
```

When I call **newTwo()**, input fields are created with the array index as follows.

```
<input type="text" name="first_name[0]" />
<input type="text" name="last_name[0]" />
```

If I call it again, the next two fields will be

```
<input type="text" name="first_name[0]" />
<input type="text" name="last_name[0]" />
```

my desired output for the previous second call would be

```
<input type="text" name="first_name[1]" />
<input type="text" name="last_name[1]" />
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have `var $i = 0;` inside the function, you're creating a new variable and initializing it to `0` every time you run the function. If you want to use a variable that maintains its value between function calls, you need to declare it outside the function. For example:

```
var $i = 0;
function newTwo()
{
    createInput("first_name[" + $i + "]");
    createInput("last_name[" + $i + "]");
    $i++;
}
```

Or if you *really* want to avoid making `$i` global you could create a [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) around it like this:

```
var newTwo = (function() {
    var $i = 0;
    return function() {
        createInput("first_name[" + $i + "]");
        createInput("last_name[" + $i + "]");
        $i++;
    };
})();
```

Note that there are subtle differences between this and the previous version. See these questions for more details:

- [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1)
- [`var functionName = function() {}` vs `function functionName() {}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: Good description of why the asker was having the problem and how to solve it!

Comment: @cecilli0n Sorry, I should have been more clear. *Both* are closures, but the second has an IIFE around the variable, too. I've updated for clarity. Glad I could help :)

Comment: Thanks, from what I read about JS so far avoiding globals seems to be the best way to go.